# Deep search and sorting

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

So my database is like this - in the picture attached. Now, I have three classes in total but I want to do it in a way that it will show only the classes that you're part of.  There is a collection inside the CLASSES which is MEMBERS. The members contain the ID of the users in that particular class. And the IDs have information of the user.  I want to do it in a way that will just show the classes you join. Please how do I go about the sorting in Firebase??

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has limitations for queries where you cannot query in collections where the user might not have access through rules.

To avoid this situation, you have two main options:

- Maintain an array of
  classes for the User which you can loop and get each class
  individually.
- Or, ensure each class document is readable in rules and do a collection group query where all classes contain an array of member UIDs.

Both options are valid but have different pros and cons.